# EMR serverless inside VPC S3 connectionTimeOut

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc

I have an EMR serverless application which runs a Spark pipeline. This pipeline has an AWS keyspaces sink. Since Keyspaces cannot be accessed without VPC from EMR serverless, I have added a VPC and I have associated 3 private subnets to it. The VPC has a gateway with rules setup to access S3. However, my EMR serverless application fails to start because it is unable to access the bucket which has my executable jar. I have given full S3 permissions to access all the buckets inside my S3 account. Following is the error I get:

`Job failed, please check complete logs in configured logging destination. ExitCode: 1. Last few exceptions: Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to my-source-bucket-use1.s3.amazonaws.com:443`

When I run the same job from an EMR serverless application without VPC, the job is able to connect to S3, fetch the jar, read my source files inside S3. However, this fails while writing to Keyspaces.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.